# Does constitution modifier math into racial HD health in DnD 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, hit-points

If a PC with 18 CON is playing a race that has 2d10 racial HD, and rolls 5 and 3, would he start his first class level with 5+3 + class HD or 9+7 + class HD?

I couldn't seem to find whether constitution modifier affects racial hit dice or not. Somehow, losing out two levels with two d10 hit dice is... unlucky for just 8 health. 16 HP on the other hand makes it a lot better due to high CON score.

Answer (score 9):

Reading the constitution entry in the players handbook on page 10

> You apply your character's constitution modifier to: each roll of a Hit Die.

This clearly states each hit die and not class hit die, therefore you should add it to each hit die you have regardless of source.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like good news, since I really had no idea whether CON modifier applies to racial hit die before the character starts leveling in a class. It wasn't even about the hitdie source, just wondered whether it applied or not. I'll accept the answer in ~5 min.

Comment: Does make me wonder, you get full HD at first level, would that affect racial HD as well?

Comment: @Fering: Yes, but only for PCs. (That is, monsters do not receive full first HD.)

Comment: Would the full HD apply to the PC's first class level, or only the first racial HD ?

Comment: @Shark "Monster class" goes first (you can be a character with only "monster class" and no PC class) thus your first HD is monster HD and you get your first HD full.

Comment: Thanks again. Luckily for me that his class HD is the same as racial HD (d10) so I'll just let him have a full HD when we continue the "making of characters" next session.... I somehow forgot about the "full HD on first level" :/

Comment: I had actually been wondering if ALL the initial HD at first level would be full, but it does make sense that only 1 gets it